# Installation of imagemagick-native node with linuxbrew

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install imagemagick-native. It will through an error

i am using command to install.

```
 npm install imagemaick-native --save

    > imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install /home/kspx/Desktop/MyData/Projects/Node/vcc-api/node_modules/imagemagick-native
    > node-gyp rebuild

    /bin/sh: 1: Magick++-config: not found
    gyp: Call to 'Magick++-config --ldflags --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/kspx/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:308:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/home/kspx/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/kspx/Desktop/MyData/Projects/Node/vcc-api/node_modules/imagemagick-native
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.8.3
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
WARN VinCompass@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN VinCompass@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN VinCompass@0.0.1 No license field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the imagemagick-native package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs imagemagick-native
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls imagemagick-native
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kspx/.npm/_logs/2017-05-15T05_30_58_940Z-debug.log
```

please guys give me the solution. how can I fix this problem?
 i was try all the ubuntu commond. even I update node and npm to latest version. atill Getting the sam error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation.

Install ImageMagick with headers before installing this module. Tested with ImageMagick 6.7.7 on CentOS 6 and Mac OS X Lion, Ubuntu 12.04 .

```
brew install imagemagick
```

or

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick-c++ ImageMagick-c++-devel
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Make sure you can find Magick++-config in your PATH. Packages on some newer distributions, such as Ubuntu 16.04, might be missing a link into /usr/bin. If that is the case, do this.

```
sudo ln -s `ls /usr/lib/\`uname -p\`-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-*/bin-Q16/Magick++-config | head -n 1` /usr/local/bin/
```

Then do :

```
npm install imagemagick-native
```